# What siddur do Satmerer Chasidim use?

Tags: minhag, prayer-book, nuschaot, chasidut-hasidism, satmar

Many Chasidic groups have a particular siddur that is used by most in that group. Does Satmer have such a siddur?

Comment: Something tells me it's not [this one](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34229&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Satmar Chassidim use סידור ישראל דוד.

A visit to any Satmar Shtiebel in NY could provide a more solid answer. I didnt pay attention to the siddur I used at the kever of the Divrei Yoel in K.Y.

Comment: Now if I could just figure out where to buy a copy for my ever-expanding siddur collection...

Answer (score 6):

Davening in a Satmer shul in Boro Park, I noticed the siddurim used there were not the typical dimensions I was used to seeing. On the first page the publisher explained that it was made that way in order to fit the (pretty narrow) shtenders (pews).

I don't remember seeing anything unusual about the siddur itself.

On Yomim Tovim many of them use the Machzor Divrei Yoel which details all the customs of the Divrei Yoel.

Answer (score 5):

The Rebbe R' Yoel Teitelbaum himself davened from סדור תפילה ישרה וכתר נהורא.

Answer (score 3):

Satmar in Montreal (R' Zalman Leib's) use *Siddur Yetev Lev* which indeed has a strange format, as mentioned by Shmuly.

Comment: Do you know of anywhere where one could purchase one?

Comment: @EzraHoerster I would imagine any Judaica store close to a major Satmar population. Obviously, you don't have that near you, but you should be able to find the phone number of a store in New York.

Answer (score 0):

That is right "The Rebbe R' Yoel Teitelbaum himself davened from סדור תפילה ישרה וכתר נהורא."
See here: "Historic Prayer Book Used by Satmar Rebbe Joel Teitelbaum OB"M" http://www.ebay.com/itm/222625469643?ul_noapp=true