# Full Kaddish - Titkabel or Titkabal?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, prayer-book, kaddish

There is this line in the full kaddish: ..תתקבל צלותהון but the nikkud in my siddur read Titkabel, while in another it says Titkabal;

What's the difference? Which one should be used? 
.

Comment: I believe this comes under the same discussion as to whether the first word is *Yitgadel* or *Yitgadal*. I'll see what I can find on my trusty "beurei" source.

Comment: What siddurim are you using?

Comment: It seems to me that it's just a matter of grammar, with some authorities saying the word is "titkabel" and others "titkabal". These sort of things should be discerned by one's nusach, siddur, etc. I'd go with the reading which is in **your** siddur.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8184

Comment: @ezra No they should be discerned by one's rabbi like any matter of jewish law and practice. The fact that you bought a siddur because it was available in your local store or was on sale has little to no bearing on the decision. No two siddurim are alike. Bring yours to your rabbi with a pencil and make yourself a siddur for you. (If your rabbi doesn't know anything about Nusach, ask him to refer you to someone who does.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Sorry, got ahead of myself. If you use a very specific nusach (such as I use Nusach Chabad), you'd always follow what was printed in the siddur. But you're right, if you're using something like an ArtScroll follow the rabbi's custom or listen next time in shul for the chazzan.

Comment: @ezra Chabad is I suspect literally the only flavor of Judaism that prints its own Siddur. Everyone else is going to fall in between various other options.

Comment: @DanF is there a difference in patach or tzere in the sence that they add something to a word?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not true. Other Hasidic groups do too. Plus Teimanim have a distinct nusach as well.

Comment: @ezra There are multiple flavors of Temani. What other groups print their own uniform Siddur? Not https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30617/759 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75328/759 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84115/759 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16469/759 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78747/759 or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50647/759

Comment: @msh210 see comment

Comment: @Levi I don't think so. The Hebrew *kabal* would mean "to accept". However, I think the fact that De Sola Poole has mentioned *Shema* may add a nuance of HOW we want G-d to accept, namely by hearing our prayers. So, it may add a double nuance by using the Aramaic form.

Comment: @DanF patach has the meaning of 'to open'; could refer to 'to be open to accept'. While tzere has the meaning of to form. On the Chava website I found out that patach is connected to the Sefirah of chochmah (concept) while tzere to binah (understanding). Thought there might be some meaning to it...

Comment: @DoubleAA, pretty sure I've seen an Ungvar chasidim sidur.

Comment: @ezra Also listening to the chazzan isn't usually a great way to find out the rabbi's opinion for you. Often the chazzan does his thing and never asks. Too often in fact.

Comment: After the question has been closed, shouldn't most of these comments be posted on the original question page instead of here?